# Hide CAS version number from startup

Tags: cas, tomcat9

We are configuring an Apereo CAS 5.2.4 application running on an Apache Tomcat 9.0.8. One thing we need and haven't been able to accomplish is to remove the CAS version from the start up log.

Does anyone know of a setting (either in CAS or Tomcat) that could be applied to suppress this message:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Chia-Ying Yang over at the CAS community, I've got an answer. That information is, actually, the Spring Boot Banner from the CAS application. So by adding the following line to the Tomcat catalina.properties file you can remove all the banners from the Tomcat logs:

```
spring.main.banner-mode=off
```

**NOTE:** This will remove banners from ***every app*** in your Tomcat installation. In my case, that was ok, since this was a single purpose web server. But it might not be appropiate for your instance.